# Do I draw a card if I enchant an opponent's Eidolon of Blossoms with Hypnotic Siren?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

The situation is just as stated in the title: my opponent controls [Eidolon of Blossoms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=eidolon%20of%20blossoms):

> Whenever Eidolon of Blossoms or another enchantment enters the battlefield under your control, draw a card.

I target the Eidolon of Blossoms with [Hypnotic Siren](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=380439), gaining control of it:

> Bestow 5UU (If you cast this card for its bestow cost, it's an
>   Aura spell with enchant creature. It becomes a creature again if it's
>   not attached to a creature.)
>
> Flying
>
> You control enchanted creature.
>
> Enchanted creature gets +1/+1 and has flying.

Do I draw a card for Hypnotic Siren coming into play?  My instinct says yes, because of rules 603.6b and 603.6d:

> 603.6b Continuous effects that modify characteristics of a permanent do so the moment the permanent is on the battlefield (and not before
>   then). The permanent is never on the battlefield with its unmodified
>   characteristics.
>
> 603.6d Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions. Continuous
>   effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger
>   conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like.

but I'm not 100% certain.  (I had it ruled the other way at FNM this evening; at the time I agreed with the ruling, but now I'm less sure.)

Answer (score 10):

First gatherer note on Hypnotic Siren:

> If you Hypnotic Siren for its bestow cost, and you gain control of a creature with a constellation ability, that ability will trigger when Hypnotic Siren enters the battlefield. You'll controll [sic] that triggered ability.

Looks like the answer is "yes".

Comment: Yes, this is because of rule 603.6d: _Normally, objects that exist **immediately after an event** are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions..._

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

> 603.6d Normally, objects that exist immediately after an event are checked to see if the event matched any trigger conditions. Continuous effects that exist at that time are used to determine what the trigger conditions are and what the objects involved in the event look like. [...]

We're trying to determine if the ability triggers for when Hypnotic Siren enters the battlefield, so we look at the state of the game immediately after the event occurs.

As soon as Hypnotic Siren enters the battlefield, Eidolon of Blossoms is under your control, and thus its ability will have triggered.

The same logic allows two creature cards with "Whenever another creature enters the battlefield under your control" to see each other enter if they enter simultaneously. e.g. Two [Bojuka Brigand](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bojuka%20Brigand) entering simultaneously get two +1/+1 counters each. This is well known behaviour.